# Very odd Swing Errors

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a login script for a game that i have made. I am currently in the process of checking the information given to make sure it is valid. I have run into the problem that when I go to check to see if 2 text fields have the same value. When they do they do the opposite of what i want it to do.

```
private void regAccConfEmailFieldFocusFocusLost(FocusEvent event) {
    if(regAccConfEmailField.getText() == regAccEmail.getText() && regAccConfEmail != null)
    {
        regAccConfEmailField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.green, 1, false));
        confEmail = true;
    }
    else
    {
        regAccConfEmailField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 1, false));
        confEmail = false;
    }
}

private void regAccConfSecQFieldFocusFocusLost(FocusEvent event) {
    if(regAccConfSecQField.getText() == null)
    {
        regAccConfSecQField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 1, false));
        secQuestion = false;
    }
    else
    {
        regAccConfSecQField.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.green, 1, false));
        secQuestion = true;
    }
}
```

This is the code that i have, and i need to know why each of these methods does the opposite of what it is given.

Say that regAccConfEmailField  and regAccEmailField both equal hello@gmail.com
It will go to the if statement and not the else. If needed, i can provide more code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 issues with this statement:

```
if (regAccConfEmailField.getText() == regAccEmail.getText() && regAccConfEmail != null)
```

- You should have the `null` check first so that it short-circuits the expression if `regAccConfEmail` is `null`
- Also use `String.equals` to compare `String` content instead of the `==` operator. The `==` operator is used to compare object references and is currently giving you the opposite of what you want as the values from the 2 fields will be different `String` objects.

You can replace with

```
if (regAccConfEmail != null && regAccConfEmailField.getText().equals(regAccEmail.getText()))
```

- Also `regAccConfSecQField.getText()` can never be `null` from a `JTextField` so replace

  if (regAccConfSecQField.getText() == null)

with

```
  if (regAccConfSecQField.getText().trim().isEmpty())
```

- Finally, you appear to be using a `FocusListener` which relys on `FocusEvents` for performing the validation. Have a look at using an [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for triggering validation on document changes.

Comment: Ah ok, i am still slightly new to this. I am currently a second year student in programming at my high school. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The border still turns green if the regAccConfEmailField.getText() returns null. It is very wierd, and this hasn't happened to me before.

Comment: Update Worked! Thanks a lot =D

Comment: [again, but I miss there trim()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14032794/714968), use DocumentListener instead of whatever