# How to "ignore/discard" Swing UI events when doing data validations on UI?

Tags: java, swing

There's a text field and when lost focus it will validate the inputs, if not passed, print out the error message (to be simple here just has an empty check). And there's a button next to the text field, it will print out the text once click on it.

As I tried, when input some text and then click the button it will trigger both the focus lost event of text field and the event of button. In a other word, it will do the validation first and then print out the input text.

Here comes my question, **what is the good approach to prevent printing out the text if the validation not passed? Or is there a way to "ignore" the click event on button if validation not passed?**

I tried to use a boolean flag which indicate the validation result and check the flag when perform the action for button, but I do not think it is a good approach. As I know there's an event dispatcher thread in Swing which deal with the events, is it possible I can cancel the events from here?

Below is a piece of code which explain the question:

```
public class SimpleDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setContentPane(content);

        final JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        textField.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter()
        {
             @Override
             public void focusLost(FocusEvent e)
             {
                 String text = textField.getText();
                 // do some validation here, if not validated 
                 // do not trigger the event on button.
                 if ("".equals(text))
                 {
                     System.out.print("please input a text!");
                 }
             }
        });
        content.add(textField);

        JButton button = new JButton("Print Text");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // action performed for button
                String text = textField.getText();
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        });
        content.add(button);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: consider using an InputVerifier (instead of the low-level focusListener) - [validation example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14041811/203657)

Comment: @kleopatra I tried with InputVerifier but seems the button can not bounced up after showing the error message, could you check my latest code and give suggestion?

Comment: didn't see your not-an-answer before (yet another reason you shouldn't post clarifications/follow-ups to your question in the answer section :-). Fix your implementation of InputVerifier and check if the button still is stuck (there had been a bug in earlier jdks, so it might)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11818080/230513).

Answer (score 1):

I faces similar issue while working on an application. I solved it like below
I created a abstract class `ApplicationFrame` which every frame in the application extends

```
public abstract class ApplicationFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    final public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if(validateInput()){
             performAction(event);
        }
    }

    /*
    * Sub class should override this method to receive any action
    */
    protected void performAction(ActionEvent event) {};

    /*
     * Sub class should override this method to perform validation
    */
    abstract protected boolean validateInput();
}
```

All Frames will now extend this base frame, as below:

```
public class Frame1 extends ApplicationFrame{
    @Override
    protected void performAction(ActionEvent event) {
        // perform action
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean validateInput() {
        // return true or false depending upon the validation results
    }
    // if you want to add Action Listener, you need to add like this:
    btnSomeButton.addActionListener(this);
}
```

If you need to handle Focus events, you can make `ApplicationFrame` or the base frame implement `FocusListener`.
This is my custom implementation to solve the problem, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- Make the button disabled on start-up
- Upon lost focus, validate the text & enable button only when the input passes validation.
- Upon start of text change, disable the button

Answer (score 0):

It's always makes sense to make ui to communicate with user. So you can show "please input a text" as the default text of the textField when nothing is entered by user.
Here is the code for such custom textField:

```
public class TextFieldWithDefaultText extends JTextField implements FocusListener{

private final String hint;

public TextFieldWithDefaultText (String $text)
{
    super($text);
    this.hint = $text;
    addFocusListener(this);
}

@Override
public void focusGained (FocusEvent $e)
{
    if (this.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        super.setText("");
    }
}

@Override
public void focusLost (FocusEvent $e)
{
    if (this.getText().isEmpty())
    {
        super.setText(hint);
    }
}

@Override
public String getText ()
{
    String typed = super.getText();
    return typed.equals(hint) ? "" : typed;
}
```

}

Write the acttionListerner for your button like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Print Text");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if(!textField.getText().isEmpty())
                System.out.println(textField.getText());
        }
    });
```

And ur textField implementation should be :

```
final TextFieldWithDefaultText textField = new TextFieldWithDefaultText ("please input a text");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I agree with you, but the question bothers me is how to "ignore" the events. :)

Comment: Actually I was ignoring the event by checking the condition of if(!textField.getText().isEmpty()). But if you want to completely avoid events to be passed to java eventQueue, I am afraid it's not possible. Handling of manual events for UI is done using Java native peers. So you check for a condition in actionPerformed() method if u want to ignore it. I know it's a kind of hack :)

Comment: If you think it answers your question, please don't forget to select it as answer :)