# Priority of events

Tags: java, swing, events

this is my problem with Swing:
imagine frame with one textfield and one button. Behind this frame there is data class with one field.

- textfield has FocusListener which updates data class field with value in textfield on FocusOut
- button has ActionListener which sends data class to the server on click

if I modify value in textfield and click the button right away, dataclass with old value is sent to server sometimes. It seems to me that there is no guarantee that FocusOut event of textfield will be processed before ActionPerformed event of button. If so, is there some way how to secure it? I mean some clean way, I do not want to go all dirty about it if not necessary.

Comment: What is `FocusOut`? I have never heard of that event.

Comment: a recent QA shows a [poor person's form validation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14041811/203657) - for more evolved control consider using a validation framework like f.i. JGoodies. Not my day for careful reading ;-)  just noticed that your question is about controlling the binding vs. validation: wrap the commit action into SwingUtilities.invokeLater should guarantee to first actually transfer the field value to the data class before committing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I modify value in textfield and click the button right away, dataclass with old value is sent to server sometimes. It seems to me that there is no guarantee that FocusOut event of textfield will be processed before ActionPerformed event of button. If so, is there some way how to secure it?

Design the form differently. That is when you click the button the ActionListener should invoke the getText() method on all the text fields on the form.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, a poor person's uni-directional binding implemented with a InputVerifier: note that the inputVerifier is guaranteed to be accessed before transfering focus (and seems to be working in current versions of the jdk - had some problems in older ones), so doing any update in the verifier should be safe as long as a focus transfer is involved in the commit action:

The verifier and some crude data object:

```
/**
 * Very simple uni-directional binding (component --> data) class.
 */
public static class BindingVerifier extends InputVerifier {

    private RawData data;
    private boolean first;
    public BindingVerifier(RawData data, boolean first) {
        this.data = data;
        this.first = first;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
        String text = ((JTextComponent) input).getText();
        if (first) {
            data.one = text;
        } else {
            data.two = text;
        }
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
        return true;
    }

}

public static class RawData {
    String one;
    String two;
    public RawData(String one, String two) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return one + "/" + two;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
final RawData data = new RawData(null, null);
JTextField first = new JTextField(20);
first.setInputVerifier(new BindingVerifier(data, true));
JTextField second = new JTextField(20);
second.setInputVerifier(new BindingVerifier(data, false));
Action commit = new AbstractAction("commit") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
};
JComponent form = new JPanel();
form.add(first);
form.add(second);
form.add(new JButton(commit));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like that. i am only giving a pseudocode.

```
private boolean check = false;

txtField FocusOutMethod {
 check = true;
}

button ActionPerformedMethod(){

 if(check){

      place your code that you want to execute in button click.

      check = false;
 }
}
```

---

By this the actionPerformed Method will only run your code after the focusOut Method's Execution.

Comment: no offense meant, but this is exactly what I meant by the line I do not want to go dirty about it :) also I have a feeling that if I'd do it like this, user would be forced to click the button twice if actionPerformed is processed before FocusOut

Comment: to click on a button the user will firstly place the mouse over that button so you can also use the MouseEntered property of that button to call the same code that you want to execute in FocusOut.... :) . I hope this will work and will fulfill your requirements....

Comment: that looks interesting. I'll still search for solution, that would not have me add another listener duplicating work of some other one, but yeah, this should actually do the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- not possible in Swing, there isn't possible to ordering of events from one Listener not in the case that two or more Listener firing events concurently

> if I modify value in textfield and click the button right away,
>   dataclass with old value is sent to server sometimes. It seems to me
>   that there is no guarantee that FocusOut event of textfield will be
>   processed before ActionPerformed event of button. If so, is there some
>   way how to secure it? I mean some clean way, I do not want to go all
>   dirty about it if not necessary.

- Focus is asynchronous, but in all cases firing proper event, issue could be in your code
- some combinations of Listeners can caused quite endless loop (events are fired wiht delay), then your controler can firing wrong orders of event

Comment: I have added sysouts to my listeners, their processing order is purely coincidental. I am afraid I am left with nothing else but dirty stuff... which by the way wouldn't have to be necessarily bad thing if programming was not involved :-)

Comment: add DocumentListener to JTextComponent, then all changes will be ..., notice but how is possible that `which updates data class field with value in textfield on FocusOut` to consumed a lots of time ???, simple remove, disable, change that